# get numbers out of html text but they are displayed as squares

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have downloaded a PDF and converted it to a html file with pdf2htmlEX .

Now the HTML file is displayed in a iframe and it shows all numbers properly but when I try to get the plain text with jquery text() or similar it just gets  as string in js Also the browsers (safari and chrome) console shows  .

So I tried to get in the original HTML file which also displays  in vs code or sublime .

then I was thinking that the problem is the code which is encoded to make html readable as plain text so I tried nano at the Terminal and it also shows  .

this is what I get displayed

```
<span class="fc0"></span>
```

but the browser seems to have no problem with displaying

`<span class="fc0"></span>`

as "23"

If I try css span display:none the numbers disappear so they have to be there and the browser can read an display them

code is in the pictures

Thank a lot.

benni

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the font family?

Comment: @font-face{font-family:ff7;src:url('data:application/font-woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAABg8AA0AAAA.......................................mbbrqmbNtI6zjrOOs46zjrOOs46zjgvMQa/b9pzp/wAfAU1Y')format("woff");}.ff7{font-family:ff7;line-height:1.000000;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;visibility:visible;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a font-family that is mapping characters outside the normal latin range to appear like latin numbers.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/local/bin/pdf2htmlEX --no-drm 1 --tounicode 1 works so you can get the unicode for the numbers but sometimes the font is not 100%.